# Proving that a finite group $G$ is solvable iff for every divisor $n$ of $|G|$ such that $(n, |G|/n) = 1$, $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I found this theorem in Dummit and Foote, and there was no proof of it there. It looks difficult to prove and I also could not find any resources online to help me out with this theorem. So here is the theorem in full:

The finite group $G$ is solvable if and only if for every divisor $n$ of $|G|$such that $(n,|G|/n) = 1$, $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

I would be grateful for the proof.

Comment: It is proved in Chapter 5 of Rotman's book "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups". The proof is a whole section called "Two theorems of P. Hall".